# Heroku how to map correctly an APEX domain

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, subdomain

I bought DNSSIMPLE to make an ALIAS but that's not working,

It's not working
https://enjkey.com/lieu/la-parare

This is working :
https://enjkey.fr/lieu/la-parare

ENJKEY.COM DNSSIMPLE CONFIG

```
ALIAS   enjkey.com  thawing-cricket-4ciojhbsgdzsnnlz7zbd1mgt.herokudns.com  3600     
CNAME   www.enjkey.com  polar-fox-r8hbw2v1900rjef2ug9n5lns.herokudns.com    3600     
MX  enjkey.com  mx01.1and1.fr   10 3600  
MX  enjkey.com  mx00.1and1.fr   10 3600  
NS  enjkey.com  ns3.dnsimple.com    3600    
NS  enjkey.com  ns1.dnsimple.com    3600    
NS  enjkey.com  ns4.dnsimple.com    3600    
NS  enjkey.com  ns2.dnsimple.com    3600    
SOA enjkey.com  ns1.dnsimple.com admin.dnsimple.com 1572351374 86400 7200 604800 300    3600    
TXT enjkey.com  v=spf1 include:spf.mailjet.com ?all 3600     
TXT enjkey.com  ALIAS for thawing-cricket-4ciojhbsgdzsnnlz7zbd1mgt.herokudns.com    3600
```

ENJKEY.FR DNSSIIMPLE CONFIG

```
ALIAS   enjkey.fr   sleepy-thicket-82uxyrwqkhvsubs0pcw85rj0.herokudns.com   3600    
CNAME   www.enjkey.fr   colorful-echidna-dvnya7dclo8vsqnvvyn6jb56.herokudns.com 3600    
MX  enjkey.fr   mx01.1and1.fr   10 3600 
MX  enjkey.fr   mx00.1and1.fr   10 3600 
NS  enjkey.fr   ns1.dnsimple.com    3600    
NS  enjkey.fr   ns3.dnsimple.com    3600    
NS  enjkey.fr   ns2.dnsimple.com    3600    
NS  enjkey.fr   ns4.dnsimple.com    3600    
SOA enjkey.fr   ns1.dnsimple.com admin.dnsimple.com 1572351318 86400 7200 604800 300    3600    
TXT enjkey.fr   ALIAS for sleepy-thicket-82uxyrwqkhvsubs0pcw85rj0.herokudns.com
```

I don't understand what's wrong

[Here Heroku Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqOZh.png)

Comment: Your question in not directly related to programming and thus may not be fit for this website. You may get better answers on https://serverfault.com/ (or maybe https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What does "not working" exactly mean?

Comment: I get an SSL error when I try to access to https://enjkey.com